# \textbf{} is not working?

Tags: beamer, fonts

I am working on a long latex(Beamer) file. Till now like 700 line.

My details setting regarding font's are,

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
```

I don't know when or how, but now in the beamer, \textbf{} command has no effect on output.

I tried to comment down

```
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
```

My best guess was \usefonttheme{} function stops the \textbf{} function.
but while commenting \usefonttheme{}, Latex stops to generate output except for the "table of content", I also don't know why this is happening.

UPD: Here is a sample slide,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%
% Choose how your presentation looks.
%
% For more themes, color themes and font themes, see:
% http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index_by_theme.html
%

\mode<presentation>

  \usetheme{Warsaw}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...\textbf{\(\(\(\)\)\)}}  

  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{bbm}



\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}



\usepackage{utopia} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\newenvironment{nscenter}
 {\parskip=0pt\par\nopagebreak\centering}
 {\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend}


\title[Awesome slides]{Awesome Slides}
\author{maruf}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{multicols}
\end{frame}


\section{Introduction}

\subsection{code code code}
\subsubsection{code}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hello World}    
The quick brown fox runs over the lazy dog \textbf{ABCDEFG}.
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textbf{asdasd}
        \item aasdasd
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add a full example of `\textbf` not working? Just one frame.

Comment: `\textbf{}` works fine with the few code fragments you show us.

Comment: I have added a sample slide. Please take a look.

Comment: Offtopic, but don't use `\usepackage{hyperref}` with beamer, it is already loaded. There is also no good reason for `multicol`, beamer has its own column environment.

Comment: @samcarter About `multicol`, that behaves differently from `beamer` columns, you wont get a ToC distributed across two columns with the latter.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. True. My personal opinion however is to better manually split the toc in two columns, as otherwise the breaking point may be suboptimal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Loading `professionalfonts` here does nothing at all, because `\usepackage{utopia}` only modifies `\rmfamily`, but you're still using sans serif for the presentation.

You get the warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmss/m/n' instead on input line 73.
```

which should be almost self-explaining: there is no boldface in Computer Modern Sans Serif.

If you want to use Utopia for your presentation, you also have to choose `\rmfamily` for the text font, which can be done with `\usefonttheme{serif}`. And `fourier` instead of `utopia` as you seem to be using math.

I reordered parts of your input. Don't use `utf8x`, it's been unmantained for a few years and `utf8` is instead actively developed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\mode<presentation>

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usecolortheme{default}
\usefonttheme{serif} % <----------- HERE
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]


\usepackage{fourier}% <------------ not utopia 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{hyperref}




\newenvironment{nscenter}
 {\parskip=0pt\par\nopagebreak\centering}
 {\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend}


\title[Awesome slides]{Awesome Slides}
\author{maruf}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{multicols}
\end{frame}


\section{Introduction}

\subsection{code code code}
\subsubsection{code}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hello World}    
The quick brown fox runs over the lazy dog \textbf{ABCDEFG}.
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textbf{asdasd}
        \item aasdasd
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]